# Thin web server freezes / times out / stops responding periodically only on GCE not on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, google-compute-engine, thin

I'm using Nginx to forward requests to two Thin web server processes on ports 5000 and 5001. Every once in a while one of the Thin processes will stop responding to requests and Nginx will spit out the following error.

```
2014/11/28 21:40:05 [error] 21516#0: *1458 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: X.X.X.X, server: www.X.com, request: "HEAD / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "http://www.example.com/"
```

Thin will go out for a couple of minutes and start responding again on its own. When that one Thin process is in a frozen state it will also not respond to wget (e.g. `wget http://127.0.0.1:5000`) nor something like a request from Python (e.g. `requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')`).

I set up three machines: two on Google Compute Engine - Debian 7.7 and Ubuntu 14.04 - and one AWS instance - Ubuntu 14.04. **This error only happens on Google Compute Engine - Amazon Web Services does not have the same problem**.

The software on all machines is as close to identical as can be. All operating systems are completely up to date through apt-get and the project is pulled from the same Git commit. I use the same deployment method on all three machines and they are all using the same Google Cloud SQL service.

I'm using Thin 1.5.1, Ruby 1.9.3-p448, and Rails 3.2.11. Updating Thin to 1.6.3 did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on this issue for far too long.

The reason it was timing out was that Google Compute Engine [closes idle TCP connections](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting#communicatewithinternet) after 10 minutes. Thin's connection to the database was being axed by GCE and Thin would just hang on a read from the database. This would explain why AWS wasn't timing out even though it was connected to the same database.

Using the suggested keep-alive settings in the previous link seems to fix the problem.